# How do I stop a sound when a new sound button is pressed

Tags: xcode, button, audio

I'm new to Xcode and I'm having an issue, if you click the sound buttons multiple times they overlap each other. How would I set my code so that if you click a button while a sound is playing it will stop the current sound playing and start the new one.

If you could post the code it would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Dominick

Here is a copy of my current code:

```
#import "Sound3ViewController.h"

@implementation Sound3ViewController

-(IBAction)playnow:(id)sender;{
soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                    pathForResource:@"winning" 
                                    ofType:@"mp3"]];

sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil]; 
    sound.delegate = self; 
    [sound play];

}

- (IBAction)play2:(id)sender {
soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                        pathForResource:@"onadrug" 
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil]; 
    sound.delegate = self; 
    [sound play];


}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [sound release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to disallow playing the sound with a variable and schedule an action that allows it again after the duration of the file. Eg:

```
boolean allowed = true

-(IBAction)playnow:(id)sender
{
    if (allowed) { // <--- ADD THIS
    allowed = false;
    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                    pathForResource:@"winning" 
                                    ofType:@"mp3"]];
    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil]; 
    sound.delegate = self; 
    [sound play];

    NSInvocation *invocation = [[NSInvocation alloc] init];
    [invocation setTarget:self];
    [invocation setSelector:@selector(allowPlaying)];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[sound duration] invocation:invocation repeats:NO];
    } // <-- AND THIS
}
-(void)allowPlaying
{
  allow = true;
}
```

Didn't test it since just wrote on the fly but you've got the general idea..

Comment: Thanks Jack, I replaced my original playnow button code with your updated code, but I received a few error messages. On line -(IBAction)playnow:(id)sender I'm receiving the error messages: "Expected expression", 'playnow' undecalred here (not in a function), Exprected "," or ";" before ":" token and on line: allow = true; I'm receiving the error: "allow" undecalred (first use in this function)

Comment: of course, since I wrote `boolean allowed = true` without semicolon (;), just add it. You don't seem so practical with Obj-C syntax.. :) Didn't care about `allow` because you will have to choose were to store it (if in C file or inside object itself as a property).

Comment: @Jack I hate to bother you again, but would you be able to give me tips on how I would go about storing it. Thanks.

Comment: @Jack Here are the error messages I am receiving with     allow = true;     error: 'allow' undeclared (first use in this function)     error: Semantic Issue: Use of undeclared identifier 'allow'

Comment: Of course, it is a typo: I defined it `allowed` and I'm using it as `allow`. Just rename every `allow` into `allowed`. But please try to learn basic syntax before digging into complex things :)

Comment: @Jack Thanks, I've been trying to learn Objective C. I thought I would give this a shot, it seems more complex than I thought. I did notice when I tested the updated code (posted above) It seems to have the same results as the original code I used. I'm assuming this is possibly an error on my part.

Comment: Cause I forgot to add the if check inside the method. Check my edit!

Comment: @Jack, thanks that did the trick, I hate to ask but I duplicated the code so I could use it for a second button and I noticed when I launched the app to test I was able to play the sound only once by clicking either of the buttons (I left the sound file the same for both buttons). Shouldn't I be able to play the sound multiple times (after it finishes playing the first time)?

Comment: @Dominick: in your code, you simply alloc/init a new instance of `AVAudioPlayer` and assign it to `sound`. This works fine the first time (because `sound` is still `nil`) but not on subsequent attempts. If `sound` is still playing you need to stop it, and you need to `release` the previous instance of `AVAudioPlayer` before you create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to objC also, so I'm not sure this is correct, but try this:

```
#import "Sound3ViewController.h"

@implementation Sound3ViewController

-(IBAction)playnow:(id)sender;{
    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                    pathForResource:@"winning" 
                                    ofType:@"mp3"]];

    // NEW STUFF
    if (sound) {
        if ([sound playing]) {
            [sound stop];
        }
        [sound release];
    }

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil]; 
    sound.delegate = self; 
    [sound play];
}

- (IBAction)play2:(id)sender {
    soundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                        pathForResource:@"onadrug" 
                                        ofType:@"mp3"]];

    if (sound) {
        if ([sound playing]) {
            [sound stop];
        }
        [sound release];
    }

    sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFile error:nil]; 
    sound.delegate = self; 
    [sound play];


}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    if (sound) {
        [sound release];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


@end
```

Comment: Thank you, I receiving a couple errors on line: if ([sound playing])  Semantic Issue: Method '-playing' not found (return type defaults to 'id') and on line: if ([sound playing]) 'AVAudioPlayer' may not respond to '-playing'

Comment: I think it should be `if ([sound isPlaying])`.

Comment: ... or I think `if (sound.playing)` would work, too. For whatever reason, objC is picky about certain constructs (properties vs. methods) that other languages treat more or less the same, so this sort of thing comes up a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
// in .h file 

#import "AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h"
//set delegate
@interface SamplesoundViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>{
AVAudioPlayer *player1;
    AVAudioPlayer *player2;
...
...
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player2;
-(IBAction)soundfirst;
-(IBAction)soundsecond;
-(IBAction)Newmethodname;



// in .m file
@implementation SamplesoundViewController

@synthesize player1,player2;

-(IBAction)soundfirst{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"soundfilefirst" ofType:@"mp3"];
   player1=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

    player1.delegate=self;
    [player1 play];
    [self performSelector:@selector(soundsecond) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.90];   
}



-(IBAction)soundsecond{
    [player1 stop];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Soundfilesecond" ofType:@"mp3"];

    player2=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

    player2.delegate=self;
    [player2 play];
    [self performSelector:@selector(Newmethodname) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];


}


-(IBAction)Newmethodname{
    [player2 stop];
     //write your code here
}
```